Mongo how to find field excluding special chars
I have this Mongo document
{
    _id: ObjectId('6616851ed50d6d1451fa8176'),
  phone: "+7(926)458-54-52",
  name: "Aboba"
}

I want to find that document if user inputs 7926, but also my filter is filtering another field as well.
I am filtering with regex phone or name but phone contains "+" and "()" so if user input is 7926, it wont be found.
How can I resolve that?
My regex:
{'$regex': f'\\w*{request_value}\\w*', '$options': 'i'}

I am filtering like that:
{$or: [name: regex, phone: regex}


Firstly, I agree with Ray's answer.

create a sanitized string, named phoneForSearch

That would allow you to also index and search better against it.
However, if you reeeaally want to just ignore special chars, then you can do something like this:
For phone numbers, separate each digit with \D* which is "one or more non-digits". First add the \D between all digits in your app/code and then search with that as a regex. So a search for 7926 against an unclean phone number could be done as:
db.collection.find({
  phone: {
    $regex: "\\D*7\\D*9\\D*2\\D*6\\D*",
    $options: "i"
  }
})

That also matches against other non-numbers like:
+7(926)458-54-52
+7===+++|||9....2++++6458-54-52
+7ssss9xxxx2yyyy6dddd-458-54-52
+7===+++|||9....2++++6458-54-52

which is why it's better to NOT do something like that.
Mongo Playground
And if you want to handle that \D insertion in Mongo, you can do it like this:
(updating)

This is as far as I got with inserting the \D into the phone search regex but it doesn't work when the regex pattern is a field name: $regex: "$phone_search_regex". https://mongoplayground.net/p/RxZZPGYPM89

You can create a sanitized string, named phoneForSearch, with all special characters removed first. Then, use your regex search on phoneForSearch.
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$set": {
      "phoneForSearch": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": {
            "$regexFindAll": {
              "input": "$phone",
              "regex": "\\d+"
            }
          },
          "initialValue": "",
          "in": {
            "$concat": [
              "$$value",
              "$$this.match"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      $expr: {
        $or: [
          // phone search
          {
            $ne: [
              -1,
              {
                "$indexOfCP": [
                  "$phoneForSearch",
                  //user input here
                  "7926"
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          // name search
          {
            "$regexMatch": {
              "input": "$name",
              // name regex here
              "regex": "^abo",
              "options": "i"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])

Mongo Playground

You are advised to "break" the phone field into separate fields so it is easier to process and format like this:
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId("6616851ed50d6d1451fa8176"),
    phone: {
      countryCode: "7",
      areaCode: "926",
      number: "4585452"
    },
    name: "Aboba"
  }
]

Mongo Playground

\\w*{request_value}\\w* So there is no way to not to exclude special chars in this regex yes? It can be completed with additional fields?

+1 to creating a sanitized string field. In your situation, I would use this answer. Create that field for all documents separately, and for new inserts & updates. And then use the regex for that.

@Zessshi aneroid's answer should be the one directly addressing your question and I am glad that it is the accepted solution. I just want to highlight the usage of creating an auxiliary search field(i.e. the sanitized phoneForSearch in my answer). If you are performing such a search frequently, you can consider materializing the field(i.e. save it to db) and index it. In this way, you can gain potential performance benefits.
